# Change of variables in a Taylor's polynomial

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

Given a regular function $f(x)$, I have to express it at a set of points $\{x+ih\}$ using a Taylor's polynomial of 4th degree, with $i\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $x,h\in\mathbb{R}$.

The solution I'm supposed to achieve is

$$f(x + ih)=f(x) + ih f^{\prime}(x)+\frac{(ih)^{2}}{2} f^{\prime \prime}(x) + \frac{(ih)^{3}}{6} f^{\prime \prime \prime}(x)+\frac{(ih)^{4}}{24} f^{(IV)}(x)+\mathcal{O}\left(h^{5}\right)$$

---

**My attempt at a solution**

What I have tried is to find the fourth-order polynomial of $f(x)$:

$$f(x)=f(x_0) + (x-x_0) f^{\prime}(x_0)+\frac{(x-x_0)^{2}}{2} f^{\prime \prime}(x_0) + \frac{(x-x_0)^{3}}{6} f^{\prime \prime \prime}(x_0)+\frac{(x-x_0)^{4}}{24} f^{(IV)}(x_0)+\mathcal{O}\left(x^{5}\right)$$

And then, to replace $x$ with $x+ih$:

$$f(x+ih)= \sum_{n=0}^{4} \frac{f^{(n)}(x_0)}{n!}(x+ih-x_0)^n+\mathcal{O}\left(x^{5}\right)$$

However, doing this I don't get the solution. What should I do to attain it?

Comment: In your approach, you have to replace $x$ with $x+ih$ but also $x_0$ with $x$. Do you still not get the right solution?

Comment: However, why to replace $x_0$ with $x$? I mean, it's true that the solution is written in terms of $f^{(n)}(x)$, but how can we justify that substitution?

Comment: $x$ is the expansion point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the function $f(x)$ in terms of another variable $z$, $f(z)$. Then, the function $f(z)$ expressed with a Taylor's polynomial centered at a point $z_0$ would be:

$$f(z)= \sum_{n=0}^{4} \frac{f^{(n)}(z_0)}{n!}(z-z_0)^n+\mathcal{O}\left((z-z_0)^{5}\right)$$

The points at which you want to evaluate the function are $z=x+ih$. If we choose $z_0$ to be $x$, then we get the expression you were looking for:

$$f(x+ih)= \sum_{n=0}^{4} \frac{f^{(n)}(x)}{n!}(ih)^n+\mathcal{O}\left(h^{5}\right)$$

Comment: First line should be $O((z-z_0)^5)$

Comment: Edited, thank you.